# Empty file received using HTTP Post method

Tags: http, inputstream

I'm trying to download a file using HTTP, and here is the code.
With this, I have a directory made with a correct name, and a file within the directory made with a correct name, but there is NOTHING WRITTEN in the file.

```
PostMethod post = new PostMethod(serverUrl);
post.setRequestEntity(entity);
httpclient.executeMethod(post); 

File contentDirectory = new File(fileFullPath);
if(contentDirectory.exists() == false){
    contentDirectory.mkdir();
}

File localFile = new File(fileFullPath + File.separator + filename);

int readBuf = 0;
byte[] buf = new byte[Utils.getBufferSize()];   (BufferSize Checked)
InputStream is = null;  

is = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localFile);

while((readBuf = is.read(buf))!= -1){
    fos.write(buf, 0, readBuf);
    logger.info("readBuf : "+readBuf);
}

is.close();
fos.close();enter code here

if(localFile.exists()) Transfer_Success = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Being a noob I am, turns out all this time I was sending post method to a wrong servlet. A mistake only novices make.

So I have the bytes transferred correctly, but this time the image files can't be open due to wrong encoding type or something. I'm on to resolving this.